# Random "Parameter is not valid" error with bitmap

Tags: c#, parameters, bitmap

The method below takes in some FileInfo of a certain pdf file and will then proceed to convert that pdf into bitmaps. This method works randomly it seems. Sometimes it will finish with no problems, other times it will fail at the `using (Bitmap bmp = image.ToBitmap())` part. Once it hits that line I get a "Parameter is not valid" error. I have no clue how to fix this random error nor dissect it even further. Any help would be appreciated

```
static void ParseOutEachBitmap(FileInfo[] pdfFiles)
        {
             string BmpPath = "C:\\temp\\bmps\\";
             if (!Directory.Exists(BmpPath))
             {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(BmpPath);
             }

            using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
            {
                MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
                settings.Density = new MagickGeometry(300, 300);
                for (int p = 0; p < pdfFiles.Count(); p++)
                {
                    images.Read(@"c:\temp\pdfs\" + pdfFiles[p].Name, settings);

                    int pageNumber = 1;
                    string pdfName = pdfFiles[p].Name;

                    foreach (MagickImage image in images)
                    {
                        using (Bitmap bmp = image.ToBitmap())
                        {                          
                            Console.WriteLine("PDF Filename: " + pdfName);
                            Console.WriteLine("Page Number: " + pageNumber + " of " + images.Count);
                            pageNumber++;

                            using (tessnet2.Tesseract tessocr = new tessnet2.Tesseract())
                            {                              
                               tessocr.GetThresholdedImage(bmp, System.Drawing.Rectangle.Empty).Save("c:\\temp\\bmps\\" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".bmp");
                            }                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Randomly on the same pdf?

Comment: Yep, i'm not changing anything about the code. I'm using the same pdf and the pdf is not open in any way on my computer. It seems to work more often if I step through the method rather than just let the program run it all at once.

Comment: For now, adding a `Thread.Sleep(2000);` has seem to fix it from happening as often. Any other work around would be nice to hear about.